# Mass Assignment insecure binder configuration newtonsoft

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi, fortify

Fortify scan is reporting a vulnerability with our code even though we have separate Database models. Below is the class which is being reported as a vulnerability - Mass assignment insecure binder configuration.

```
public class StepDefinition
    {
        public Guid StepDefinitionId { get; set; }
        public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsAutomated { get; set; }
        public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
        public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
        public bool HasParameters { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StepOutcome> StepOutComes { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Dummy { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller action looks like below.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync(Guid tenantId, StepDefinition model)
```

How can we prevent this vulnerability. We are using newtonsoft json for serialization/deserialization purposes. **WHat I have noticed is if I just add a dummy param and mark it with JsonIgnore attribute this error goes away. But not getting the logic for that**. Any help will be appreciated. None of the other questions were of help.

Comment: So, ... are you suspecting this is just a tool glitch? Have you dug into what the message actually means in detail?

Comment: @Fildor Yes. Have gone through in detail on the vulnerability. Now how can we tell Fortify via newtonsoft json that it is fully ok to have all values bound. We anyway have separate objects for database and do the mapping.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Have the same problem - curious how you solved this.